# Casting unmarshaled yaml interface{} into actual struct

Tags: go, struct, yaml, slice

I the following issue: i receive information in yaml form, it can come in 2 configurations-
asingle character:

```
Character:
  Name: Stackoverflow
  Type: Awesome
```

Or in a slice of multiple characters with an optional field of slice of friends:

```
Character:
- Name: Stackoverflow
  Type: Awesome
  Friends: [Ben, John]
- Name: Facebook
  Type: Ok
```

Because I don't know which configuration will arrive I tried to unmarshal the yaml to interface{} and then cast it to one of the structs but it didn't worked out:

```
type CharacterConfig struct{
Name    string      `yaml:"Name"`
Type    string      `yaml:"Type"`
Friends []string    `yaml:"Friends,omitempty"`


var d interface{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &d)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

res, ok := d.(CharacterConfig)
if ok {
    fmt.Println("CharacterConfig are ok")
}

res, ok := d.([]CharacterConfig)
if ok {
    fmt.Println("[]CharacterConfig are ok")
}
```

But I don't receive any of the prints... when I debug is I can see the unmarshal into interface worked, but non of the castings.
I know I can just unmarshal straight into the structs, but I don't understand wht what i did didn't work.

Comment: Note on terminology: Go doesn't have type casting at all. What you're talking about is a type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmarshaling into `interface{}` will not magically guess you want the result in your custom `CharacterConfig` struct. Unmarshaling YAML into `interface{}` will use `map[interface{}]interface{}` to represent objects, and `[]interface{}` to represent lists / arrays, recursively.

So the type assertions above yield `ok = false` because the values stored in them are maps or slices of `interfaces{}`. You may type assert those types, and the assertion will succeed, but you won't be any closer in getting those values as your structs.

Also note that your input YAML needs another wrapper layer:

```
type Character struct {
    CC CharacterConfig `yaml:"Character"`
}

type CharacterList struct {
    CCs []CharacterConfig `yaml:"Character"`
}
```

So an easy way would be to first try to unmarshal into a value of type `Character`, and if that succeeds, you're done. If not, try to unmarshal again, this time into `CharacterList`.

Here's an example code that does that:

```
func unmarshal(data []byte) {
    var c Character
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, &c)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("It's Character: %+v\n", c)
        return
    }

    var cl CharacterList
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &cl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("It's CharacterList: %+v\n", cl)
}
```

Testing it like this:

```
func main() {
    unmarshal([]byte(src))
    unmarshal([]byte(src2))
}

const src = `Character:
  Name: Stackoverflow
  Type: Awesome`

const src2 = `Character:
- Name: Stackoverflow
  Type: Awesome
  Friends: [Ben, John]
- Name: Facebook
  Type: Ok`
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vpterBpSqwS)):

```
It's Character: {CC:{Name:Stackoverflow Type:Awesome Friends:[]}}
It's CharacterList: {CCs:[{Name:Stackoverflow Type:Awesome Friends:[Ben John]} {Name:Facebook Type:Ok Friends:[]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what you did but without interface:

```
type CharacterConfig struct{
    Name    string      `yaml:"Name"`
    Type    string      `yaml:"Type"`
    Friends []string    `yaml:"Friends,omitempty"`
}

var a CharacterConfig
var b []CharacterConfig

err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &a)
if err == nil {
    // a is valid format
}

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &b)
if err == nil {
    // b is valid format
}
```